# Using jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application, I have a search box in the navbar using jQuery's autocomplete. I'm using this on the User's index action. Everything works good, except if they click on a user's name from the dropdown, I want it to go to their profile page.

Users controller:

```
def index
  if params[:term]
    @users = User.order(:name).where("LOWER(name) like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    render json: @users.map(&:name)
  end
  if params[:users_name]
    @users = User.search(params[:users_name])
  end
end
```

Search bar:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', :role => 'search', :class => "navbar-form navbar-right" do %>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <%= autocomplete_field_tag :users_name, '', users_path, :placeholder => "Search", :required => true, :class => "form-control transition" %><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and my routes for users are basic with just

```
resources :users
```

users/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <% if @users %>
      <ol class="list-inline">
        <%= render @users %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_user.rb:

```
I have the appropriate file with what I want displayed here as well.
```

Like I mentioned, the autocomplete works fine, when i start typing names, users name will dropdown. The problem I'm having is if they start typing justin and "justin timberlake" is one of the dropdowns, and they click on Justin Timberlake I want it to go to his profile page `profile_page(@user)`

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are few ways to achieve this, but one simple solution would be doing this...

users_controller.rb

```
def index
  if params[:term]
    @users = User.order(:name).where("LOWER(name) like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
    payload = []
    # build up data set
    @users.each do |u|
      payload.push({label: u.name, value: u.id})
    end
    render json: @users.map(&:name)
  elsif params[:users_name]
    @users = User.search(params[:users_name])
  end
end
```

In your JS code

```
$("#element_name").autocomplete({
  source: "/user",
  ...
  select: function (e, d) {
    // redirect to the user profile page..
    window.location = "/users/" + d.item.value;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @YosepKim. The autocomplete results still are not acting as links though. but everything else is working good.